# How to return a serialized array in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serializearray

I have the following problem:

I have a form and I want to catch the input data. When I want to obtain string, which stores the input from this form, I simply do:

`JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray())`

But instead of obtaining string, I would like to have an array with my data (preferably, a serialized array).

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me at least, 'serialized' *means* 'turned into a string'. What does a serialized array look like, if not a string?

Comment: I would like to obtain the results from the form, but I want to store them in an array (not in a string), that is what I have meant. For example, I want to have an array, similar to this: [1, 2, 3] instead of this: '[1, 2, 3]'.

Answer (score 1):

`.serializeArray()` creates an array of objects,`JSONStringify()` converts it to string

You can use

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't stringify the array.

JSON's `.serializeArray()` method returns an array of the all the input values in the form